# Trigger creation query failed

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, when data is inserted into third table, I am checked whether newly inserted row has field value in table1. If value exists then I am moving the same row from table3 to table2. My code is like below, But I am getting error while executing this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER onRosterAdd
 AFTER INSERT ON yet_tobe
 FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE NEW.jid = (users.username + "_1")) > 0 
     THEN 
       INSERT INTO rusers SELECT * FROM yet_tobe WHERE yet_tobe.id = NEW.id;
       DELETE FROM yet_tobe where yet_tobe.id = NEW.id;
     END        
   END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And here is the error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO rusers SELECT * FROM yet_tobe WHERE yet_tobe.id = NEW.id;

How can I fix this.

Comment: Remove select before case

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Still error is there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER onRosterAdd
BEFORE INSERT ON yet_tobe
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   IF (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE CONCAT(username,"_1")=NEW.jid)>0
   THEN 
      INSERT INTO rusers SELECT * FROM yet_tobe WHERE yet_tobe.id = NEW.id;
      DELETE FROM yet_tobe where yet_tobe.id = NEW.id;
   END IF;
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c30c)

Comment: Still I could not execute :(

Comment: @redV Updated, was a typo, should be END IF; not END only

Comment: Thanks for the code, it is executed but when I am trying to insert some value in `yet_tobe` if the id exists in table1 then it is saying that cannot invoke this as this is being used by stored function/trigger. And asking me to discard changes

Comment: @redV Use `BEFORE` at the place of `AFTER`, updated the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49080/discussion-between-redv-and-codebird)